# Keras CTC Loss input

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use CTC for speech recognition using keras and have tried the CTC example [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py#L457). In that example, the input to the CTC `Lambda` layer is the output of the softmax layer (`y_pred`). The `Lambda` layer calls `ctc_batch_cost` that internally calls Tensorflow's `ctc_loss`, but the [Tensorflow `ctc_loss` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss) say that the `ctc_loss` function performs the softmax internally so you don't need to softmax your input first. I think the correct usage is to pass `inner` to the `Lambda` layer so you only apply softmax once in `ctc_loss` function internally. I have tried the example and it works. Should I follow the example or the Tensorflow documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loss used in the code you posted is different from the one you linked. The loss used in the code is [found here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/backend/ctc_batch_cost)

The keras code peforms some pre-processing before calling the `ctc_loss` that makes it suitable for the format required. On top of requiring the input to be not softmax-ed, tensorflow's `ctc_loss` also expects the dims to be `NUM_TIME, BATCHSIZE, FEATURES`. Keras's `ctc_batch_cost` does both of these things [in this line.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/backend.py#L3524)

It does log() which gets rid of the softmax scaling and it also shuffles the dims so that its in the right shape. When I say gets rid of softmax scaling, it obviously does not restore the original tensor, but rather `softmax(log(softmax(x))) = softmax(x)`. See below:

```
def softmax(x):
"""Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
return e_x / e_x.sum()


x = [1,2,3]
y = softmax(x)
z = np.log(y) # z =/= x (obviously) BUT
yp = softmax(z) # yp = y #####
```

Comment: yes, but `ctc_batch_cost` calls tensorflow's `ctc_loss` internally.

Comment: You are right. I am exploring whether double softmax would make any difference compared to applying it once. Have you found any conclusive answers?

Comment: no, I haven't. I currently switching to full Tensor Flow implementation in favor of flexibility and multiple GPU support. but it would be nice if you could share your exploration result with me, it's quite interesting.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you still care, but I updated my answer above that explains that both of them are right.

Comment: ah yes, i didn't pay much attention to that line than the axis swap. It's clear now. thanks @Prophecies